# Jigsaw / Jlink for modular Java projects to minimize JRE size

Tags: java, java-11, java-module, java-platform-module-system, jlink

I am trying to understand the differences or the associations between these two principles / feature for Java modular projects.

I am trying to minimize the JRE size by reduce the use of the external libraries / modules.

In order to do that, I made some quick research and  I found these two "principles" that may help me.

Now, I don't understand if these two things are different or if they link to one another somehow. How should I use these to reach my goal?
Can you please specify what would be the best solution for me? In the module-info.java do I have to specify manually what do I need?

Is there a possibility to generate the module-info.java files? (I guess not but I am just asking). Can I use it with JDK Amazon Correto 11?

Comment: Which “two principles” are you talking about?

Comment: @Holger  I was talking about jigsaw vs jlink. I saw that jlink may be proper and suitable for what I am trying to do.
Practically I need a smaller JRE just for my application. Jlink is the solution, but I am wondering how to generate those module-info.java files which contains the packages to import and export.

Comment: Neither “jigsaw” nor “jlink” is a principle. And since jlink is part of jigsaw, I still don’t understand what “jigsaw vs jlink” or “the differences … between these two principles” is supposed to mean. You can use [`jdeps`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeps.htm#JSWOR690) to analyze dependencies, it even has e `--generate-module-info` option, but don’t ask us for a complete tutorial.

Comment: Man that's the answer I needed in the first place. I don't ask  for full tutorial. jdeps will help me. And didn't know how jlink is part of jigsaw. So you could be nice to help me with this. That's why I quoted "priciples". I may sound stupid I know. Because it's an hour since I looked up into those terms. Be nicer. I don't ask for everything done. just some short explanation. I will research for the rest. Thanks.

Comment: No offense intended. We sometimes get confused by unclear question ourselves and think, we might have missed something. So we ask. Jigsaw is the [old project name](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) under which the Java module system was developed. You don’t need to know it or use it. But if you encounter it, you can treat it as a synonym for the Java module system.

Comment: No problem. seems lik jlink will help me. Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: By the way, I think this is an interesting topic to discuss, I don't get why I have a "-1" there. :) Thanks for appreciation.

Comment: Don’t try to comprehend every vote. That won’t lead anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

you actually posted multiple questions.

> I am trying to minimize the JRE size by reduce the use of the external libraries / modules.

Having fewer dependencies is always a good goal. jigsaw/JPMS will not help you with that. On the contrary: In fact you could end up with multiple versions of the same dependency, which wasn’t possible before.

Hint: JLink and JIGSAW/JPMS will not help you with reducing your dependencies.

> How should I use these to reach my goal?

If your goal is to have a stripped-down JVM shipped with your application, you should look [into the jlink binary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm), which is part of the JDK since Java 9.

If you are using maven, you could invoke it by using the [maven-jlink-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jlink-plugin/). There are similar plugins for gradle and even for maven (e.g. javafx-specific plugins).

> Can you please specify what would be the best solution for me?

That is something we cannot answer. YMMV – maybe [quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) is worth looking at as well, which creates native images (yes, os- and arch dependent native binaries).

> In the module-info.java do I have to specify manually what do I need?

Yes, for your modules. You can use [moditect](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) if you use maven to inject a module-info.class file into your dependencies, at least if you are using maven as a build system.

> Is there a possibility to generate the module-info.java files? I guess not but I am just asking)

Already answered in the comments, yes, [by using jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html).

> Can I use it with JDK Amazon Correto 11?

Yes, they also ship both jlink and jdeps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I will try to look up all the details. Seems like JLINK is the solution. A custom runtime image would help me here. I will come back with an answer as I implement what I need. And yes, I am using maven. Thank you.

Comment: How can I enable module-info.java creation on my modules in Intellij? Seems like if I create it manually it doesn't recognize it as a module description file. I have amazon correto 11. And the project is setup to use latest version of java.

Comment: Try Project Settings (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) and then select at least Java 9. Add a module-info.java file in the java root folder (may not reside in packages). You can then Alt-Enter on an import, a "add requires" should pop up.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's kinda messy over the project structure because I have two modules with the same package path so it collide somehow. I don't know if there is a trick for this. Plus on the 'requires' fileds it complains that the same package is from two dependencies. I think this would save me by excluding one of the dependencies from it's parents. For example for java.persistance comes from javax.persistance / jakarta.persistance. Dirty thing. Is there a proper fix for this?